# Qual a maneira correta de adicionar um botão no arquivo php

Tags: php

Estou precisando colocar um botão em meu arquivo php onde irei utilizar para cadastrar. Segue o código.

```
echo "<button type=\'"button"'\ class=\'"btn btn-default btn-lg"'\>";
        echo "<span class=\'"glyphicon glyphicon-plus"'\ aria-hidden=\'"true"'\></span> Inserir";
    echo "</button>";
```

Qual a maneira correta de fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa disso, Renan.
Feche a rotina PHP com o **?>** e adiciona o botão na linguagem HTML mesmo.

Mas se for realmente necessário fazer isso que você quer:

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-lg'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span> Inserir </button>";
```

Pense sempre assim:

**"** Aspas Simples '**dentro**' de Aspas Duplas **"**

ou

**'** Aspas Duplas "**dentro**" de Aspas Simples **'**

Answer (score 2):

Procure utilizar mais html e menos php. Um exemplo:

```
....
?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg <?php echo $algumaClasse; ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <?php echo $algumaAcaoParaBotao; ?>
</button>
<?php
....
```

Esta seria a melhor forma.